# Struggling to make phaser work with javascript in local server

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

So after ~6 hours of trying to make this work and washed out of ideas , here i am.

Its my first time with JS and Phaser 3.16.2.

I'm working on Visual Studio Code , running a local server via 'live server' plug-in.

The supposed correct output would be "Simple Game" and after that an icon file.

This is king of weird cause i am not getting any errors or warning but when i run the index.html file , the .js files doesn't produce any output.

phaser.js is in the same folder as game.js file.

Things i tried so far :

- debugging the code in *game.js* file ( i got an error window not
  defined ).
- checking the syntax of the code multiple times.
- check for problems on the server side (everything executes correctly
  ).
- I've read all the similar posts on the web.
- changed multiple image files in case something odd blocked the image
  from appearing on the screen.
- tried running on chrome,edge.

I am not really familiar with JavaScript so i do not really know what else path to follow to solve this.

Here are the files so far:

**32744.jpg**

**phaser.js**

**index.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang ="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Simple Game</title>
        <script>src="js/phaser.js"</script>
        <script>src="js/game.js"</script>
    </head>

    <body>
      <h1>Simple Game</h1>
      <div id="content"></div>
      </body>
</html>
```

**game.js**

```
var SimpleGame = (function() {
    function SimpleGame() {
        //create our phaser game
        //800 width
        //600 height
        //Phaser.AUTO determines the renderer automatically (canvas,webgl)
        // {preload:this.preload,create:this.create} -- function to call for our start game
        this.game = new Phaser.Game(800,600,Phaser.AUTO,'content',{preload:this.preload,create:this.create});
    };
    SimpleGame.prototype.preload = function () {
        //add our logo image to the assets class under the
        //key->logo, we are also setting the background colour
        //so its the same as the background colour in the image
        this.game.load.image('logo',"assets/32744.jpg");
        this.game.stage.backgroundColor=0xB20059;

    };
    SimpleGame.prototype.create = function () {
        //add the logo sprite to the game, position it in the 
        //center of the screen,and set the anchor to the center of 
        //the image so its centered properly.Theres a lot of centering in that last sentece
        var logo = this.game.add.sprite(this.game.world.centerX,this.game.world.centerY,'logo');
        logo.anchor.setTo(0.5,0.5);
    };

    return SimpleGame;
}); 

//when the page has finished loading,create our game 
global.window.onload = function() {
    var game = new SimpleGame();


};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to run **Phaser 2.x.x/CE** code with **Phaser 3.x.x**. No wonder you're getting these errors. Phaser 2.x.x/CE and 3.x.x are different from each other. Phaser 3 was written from scratch, so internals are totally different.

Here are some links to get you started with Phaser 3.

[Getting started with Phaser 3](https://phaser.io/tutorials/getting-started-phaser3)

[Making your first game with Phaser 3](https://phaser.io/tutorials/making-your-first-phaser-3-game)

[Phaser 3 Examples](https://labs.phaser.io/)

[Phaser 3 Docs](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/index.html)

[Phaser 3 FAQs](https://github.com/samme/phaser3-faq/wiki)

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

Changed the way i import the engine , lowered the version of the engine , placed the code directly inside the  tag.
Worked like a charm.

I still do not know exactly the reason behind the failure at my first try , but the point is it worked. Maybe the newer version is not so stable YET.